# How to add or subtract 1 to a sum based on a certain value in a text?

Tags: python

After reading a text, I need to add `1` to a sum if I find a `(` character, and subtract `1` if I find a `)` character in the text. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I tried at first:

```py
file = open("day12015.txt")

sum = 0
up = "("

for item in file:
    if item is up:
        sum += 1
    else:
        sum -= 1
print(sum)
```

I have this long text like the following example `(((())))((((( ...`. If I find a `)`, I need to subtract `1`, if I find a `(`, I need to add `1`. How can I solve it? I'm always getting `0` as output even if I change my file manually.

Comment: Some advice: `sum` is a built-in function in Python. Using it as a variable overwrites the built-in function which can lead to frustrating and hard-to-find bugs. The other thing you should get into the habit of doing is using `with open("some_file_path") as file`, a context manager which automatically closes the file after you're done working with it. Also, you should be using the equality operator `==` instead of `is` for your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

your for loop only gets all the string in the file so you have to loop through the string to get your desired output.

**Example .txt**

```
(((())))(((((
```

**Full Code**

```
file = open("Data.txt")

sum = 0
up = "("

for string in file:
    for item in string:
        if item is up:
            sum += 1
        else:
            sum -= 1
print(sum)
```

**Output**

```
5
```

Hope this helps.Happy Coding :)

Comment: I'd recommend showing OP that there are other things in their code that can be improved. They should be using a context manager to read the file; they shouldn't be using `sum` as a variable; they should use `==` for equality checks, not `is`, etc.

Comment: yeah i will change the sum variable for sure .... i edited with == and i solve it... what does it means OP? and what is a context manager?

Answer (score 1):

That's simply a matter of counting each character in the text. The sum is the difference between those counts. Look:

```
from pathlib import Path

file = Path('day12015.txt')

text = file.read_text()

total = text.count('(') - text.count(')')
```

For the string you posted, for example, we have this:

```py
>>> p = '(((())))((((('
>>> p.count('(') - p.count(')')
5
>>>
```

Just for comparison and out of curiosity, I timed the `str.count()` and a loop approach, 1,000 times, using a string composed of 1,000,000 randoms `(` and `)`. Here is what I found:

```py
import random
from timeit import timeit

random.seed(0)

p = ''.join(random.choice('()') for _ in range(1_000_000))


def f():
    return p.count('(') - p.count(')')


def g():
    a, b = 0, 0
    for c in p:
        if c == '(':
            a = a + 1
        else:
            b = b + 1
    return a - b


print('f: %5.2f s' % timeit(f, number=1_000))
print('g: %5.2f s' % timeit(g, number=1_000))
```

```
f:  8.19 s
g: 49.34 s
```

It means the loop approach is 6 times slower, even though the `str.count()` one is iterating over `p` two times to compute the result.

Comment: FWIW, this requires iterating over the input twice.

Comment: Indeed. But I'm pretty sure it is not an issue in this case.

Comment: Sure, but OP should learn how to write basic algorithms, not blindly rely on built-in functions. Answers like these are fine, but I recommend showing the problem first, showing the solution, and *then* saying "with all that out of the way, here's how you can do it much more easily...". Just my opinion, of course.

Comment: I agree. But it is also good to learn what the language already do for them.

Comment: Agreed as well, hence my edit.

Comment: i preferred to solve mine reasoning to improve my understanding, my main error was not put the equality check

Comment: Fair enough. One must do whatever they must do. :-)

Comment: Just for comparison and completely out of curiosity, I timed both approaches. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to sum +1 for "(" character and -1 for ")".

Do it directly specifying what to occur when you encounter this character. Also you need to read the lines from a file as you're opening it. In your code, you are substracting one for every case that is not "(".

```py
file = open("day12015.txt")
total = 0

for line in file:
    for character in line:
        if character == "(":
            total += 1
        elif character == ")":
            total -= 1

print(sum)
```

Comment: thank you i put variables on the beginning that are superfluos

Comment: yeah thank you so much... i tried after this to print the first index that gives me the floor -1 but i can't figure out which is my error. i tried this:
file = open("day12015.txt")
floor = 0

for string in file:
    for item in string:
        if item == "(":
            floor += 1
        else:
            floor -= 1
        for i in item:
            if floor < 0:
                floor = string.index(item) + 1
                break
            print(floor)

but it gives me back the same floor and not the first index of with the value -1 on the floor. Can you help me out?